# Azure AD B2C - Recover your Account differs from Reset Password

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I am using Azure AD B2C (and MSAL), and have sign up / sign in, edit profile and password reset policies enabled and working.

However, I have noticed an anomaly if you are going through the Edit Profile workflow and select Recover Account, the flow returned is not the same as the Reset Password policy linked to the login flow.

When the user enters identity info and the captcha, it returns the error 'your organisation has not set up a password reset policy', even though I have as it works if you choose it on sign in.

This is how I set password reset

```
     AuthenticationResult authResult = await ADB2CClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(accounts, EditProfilePolicy), UIBehavior.NoPrompt, string.Empty, null, AuthorityEditProfile, App.UiParent);
```

This is how I set Edit Profile

```
    authenticationResult = await ADB2CClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, firstAccount, UIBehavior.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, AuthorityResetPassword, App.UiParent);
```

However, as mentioned the Recover your Account option on Edit Profile clearly triggers a different flow and I'm unclear how to account for that in Policies?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are passing different policy names when you are getting authenticationResult. For example, In case of password reset policy, you are passing "**AuthorityEditProfile**" to get the authentciationResult and in case of edit profile, you are passing "**AuthorityResetPassword**".

Could you change it and try it again.

For edit profile:

AuthenticationResult authResult = await ADB2CClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, GetUserByPolicy(accounts, EditProfilePolicy), UIBehavior.NoPrompt, string.Empty, null, **AuthorityEditProfile**, App.UiParent);

For password reset:

authenticationResult = await ADB2CClient.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes, firstAccount, UIBehavior.SelectAccount, string.Empty, null, **AuthorityResetPassword**, App.UiParent);

Comment: Something's changed - I went to try your suggestion and now the flow no longer expects you to validate who you are before editing profile. But I haven't changed any code - I simply wanted to validate before & after. How very odd.